# I want to give users ten coins each time they fill out one form

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-forms

I want to give users ten coins each time they fill out one form , so i tried this code above and show this error

```
TypeError at /profile
unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'DeferredAttribute' and 'int'
error in views.py in line += 10
```

models.py

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    user_pic = models.ImageField(upload_to='img/',default="",null=True, blank=True)
    coins = models.IntegerField(default=100)
    def gives_user_coins_after_create(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
        if created:
            profile = instance.User.profile
            profile.coins += 10
            profile.save()
```

views.py

```
@login_required(login_url='accounts/login/')
def profile(request):
    # Gives the user 10 coins for fill up one form
    profile = get_user_model()
    profile.coins += 10
    profile.save()

    return render(request,'account/profile.html')
```

i tried many code but nothing work , any idea or help please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `User` model you show above is your `AUTH_USER_MODEL` then all you really need is

```
def give_coins(user, count):
    user.coins = F('coins') + count
    user.save(update_fields=('coins',))
    user.refresh_from_db(fields=('coins',))
```

(which is using `F()` to avoid (some) race conditions); there is no `.profile` you'd need to access.

You can then call this in e.g. your `FormView`'s `form_valid`:

```
class MoneyFormView(FormView):
    # ...

    def form_valid(self, request):
        give_coins(request.user, 10)
        return super().form_valid(request)
```

Comment: Thanks bro for help really you are good man ... I want ask you if you can edit answer to explain what i must add to my code i mean in views.py and models.py and form.py

Comment: what should i write in views.py

Comment: I told you what you could put in a `FormView` in your `views.py`.

Comment: ok yes thanks and   def give_coins  this in models thanks

Comment: thanks but i tried many codes and i tried to fix it when i add the code above in models.py 
it show this error        NameError name 'F' is not defined

Comment: You need to import F from django.db.models.